# Show that the projection $p:S^n\to \Bbb RP^n$ is a local diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Here, $S^n\subset\Bbb R^{n+1}$ has the canonical stereographical projection $\phi_{N,S}$ (from north and south pole respectively) as its atlas, and $\Bbb RP^n$ has the following charts as its atlas:
$$\psi_i: U_i\ni [x]\mapsto (x_1/x_i,\cdots,x_{i-1}/x_i,x_{i+1}/x_i,\cdots, x_{n+1}/x_i)\in\Bbb R^n$$
where $U_i=\{[x]\mid x\in\Bbb R^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}\,\text{and}\,x_i\ne 0\}$.

I have already done the case where $x$ is not on the "equator" i.e. $x_{n+1}\ne 0$: because we just have to check that, say when $x$ is on the upper hemisphere, the map $\psi_{n+1}\circ p\circ \phi_S(x)=\dfrac{2x}{1-\|x\|^2}$ is a local diffeomorhphism. Some calculations lead to its smooth inverse 
$$y\mapsto \frac12 y(1-(\sqrt{1+\frac1{\|y\|^2}}-\frac1{\|y\|})^2)$$
(perhaps there can be some glitches at $x = N$ i.e., $y=0$; I only check the differentiability, but not $C^1$ or higher.)

When $x$ is at the equator, i.e., $x_{n+1}=0$, my thought is to change the chart $\psi_{n+1}$ to some $\psi_i$ such that $x_i\ne 0$. This is of course possible, but would give rise to an asymmetric form of $\psi_{i}\circ p\circ \phi_S(x)$ and hence make it complicated to compute its inverse.

Perhaps I could also consider introducing new stereographic projections whose poles are different from $N,S$ into the atlas $\{\phi_{N,S}\}$ to $S^n$, but it will take some non-trivial effort to show the compatibility, I guess.

Anyway, is there a computationally economic way to complete the proof? Thanks.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question. I've seen the approach that you are taking before, so I know that it will work, but I have always viewed it as a bit of a pain. There is an alternative way:

The equivalence relation on $\mathbb R P^n$ restricts to the $n$-sphere under the action of the two element group $G=\{1,-1\}$ (the antipodal map) so that $\mathbb R P^n := S^n/G$. The action is smooth, proper, and free (of course), so we see that projection $\pi:S^n \to \mathbb R P^n$ is a smooth submersion (and with a bit more effort, we can see a local homeomorphism.)

Comment: @AndresMejia how do you conclude it is smooth (in the differentiability sense)?

Comment: Lee's book theorem 9.19 should do it, I searched it on SE, and here is a post that references it: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496571/under-what-conditions-the-quotient-space-of-a-manifold-is-a-manifold

Comment: @AndresMejia that would be definitely too advanced for me, but thanks still. I now think it might be best to introduce new compatible charts into the stereographic atlas of $S^n$. (Verification won't be so hard, since only orthogonal transformations would be involved, i suppose).

Comment: Okay, I hope that somebody gives you a good answer, I would try, but  I think that *this* is a little too hard for me :).