# Is a quotient space of a smooth manifold by a properly discontinuous group action also able to be smooth manifold?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

$X$ is a smooth manifold (Hausdorff, locally Euclid) with an action by a group $G$. I have the following questions.

1. Quotient space $X/G$ has a quotient topology. Does $X/G$ have Hausdorff property?
2. Let $\pi : X \to X/G$ be a quotient map. Is $\pi$ locally homeomorphic?

Comment: Perhaps this answers your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/496652/26501 (look at the first displayed statement) Note that you are missing two hypotheses: the action should be smooth, and it should be free.

Comment: I'm thinking about a diffeomorphisms group of X. In this case, the action seems smooth and meets the hypothesis of the theorem.

Comment: You also have to assume that the action is proper, otherwise, even if the action is free and smooth, the quotient need not be Hausdorff: Think about the additive group of rational numbers acting on the real line by translations.