# How is a vector bundle a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles

Studying the basics of differential theory in Foundations of Mechanics 2nd edition I got confused by definitions.

A vector bundles atlas is defined as a maximum family $\{(U,\phi)\}$ of local bundle charts covering a space, and whose transition map is a linear bundle isomorphism.

There is neigther any word about existence of a homeomorphism $\Phi:\pi^{-1}(U)\to U\times \mathbb{R}^k$ nor any proof of it, meanwhile it is a condition in order to a vector bundle to be a manifold.

Absence of this constraint in definition makes me think that this can be proved, but I have no idea how. All the vector bundles manuals I found put it as a definition.

Would appreciate any help!

Upd:
Lemme display the full thought in order to figure it out.

We take covering of a smooth manifold $M$ and make from it a family of local bundle charts, bijectivelly attaching to each neighborhood Cardesian product: $A=\{(u,\phi)|U\in \tau(M),\phi:U \longleftrightarrow U \times F \}$.

We put on a constraint in order to have an atlas: $\forall(U,\phi),(V,\psi)\in A \;\;\;\phi\circ\psi^{-1}\vert_{\phi(U)\cap\psi(V)}$ is a local bundle isomorphism, so by definition it's a diffeomorphism.

Then we define for vector bundles $A_1$ and $A_2$: $A_1 \sim A_2 \stackrel{def}{\iff} A_1 \cup A_2$ is vector bundle.

Then $\mathcal{A}_{max}=A/\mathord{\sim}$, and $\forall(U,\phi)\in
\mathcal{A}_{max}\;\;\;U:=\pi_{\sim}(U)$.

Under certain conditions we can induce smooth structure onto $\mathcal{A}_{max}$. [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496571/under-what-conditions-the-quotient-space-of-a-manifold-is-a-manifold]

As far as finite-dimensional normed space $F\simeq\mathbb{R}^k, U\times F\simeq U\times \mathbb{R}^k$. The final detail to prove that $A$ is a manifold is somehow making $U$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$, but it is a submanifold of $M$.

How can we do this?

Comment: The definition of a manifold in this book only requires the chart maps to be bijections and not homeomorphisms. To elaborate, this is the case because the natural topology which is defined through the maximal atlas will lead to the right topology under which the maps are also homeomorphisms.

Comment: @P-A, ok, could you please give then an explanation how the maximal atlas defines the natural topology?
Although, this still for me not clear have we can find such a bijective $\Phi$

Comment: I'd suggest to read through all the relevant definitions again. You'll note that the vector bundle charts are bijective by definition. The natural manifold topology of $M$ is defined by the basis $\mathcal{B} = \{ V \,\vert\,  (\psi,V) \in \mathcal{A}_\text{max}  \}$ with maximal atlas $\mathcal{A}_\text{max}$.

Comment: @P-A, please, check the update of question. I almost got it by my own, and I need a little clarification on details

Comment: I have to repeat what I was saying before. Using the definitions of the book you are studying, it should be clear that a vector bundle structure is automatically also a $\mathcal{C}^\infty-$-structure, so it's automatically a smooth manifold. The reason for that being that you don't ask of the chart maps to be homeomorphisms.

Comment: If you are struggling to show that this definition of a manifold with the natural manifold topology is equivalent to the "usual" definition with homeomorphisms, I think it's better to do this in a separate question.

Comment: @P-A, I'm struggling with constructing a bijective map $\phi: U \times F \to \mathbb{R}^{k+m}$ in order to introduce a manifold structure on an atlas

Comment: A (local) vector bundle chart is a bijection onto a local vector bundle $W'\times F'$, i.e. onto the open subset of a finite dimensional real vector space. This is exactly what you need for a manifold.

Comment: @P-A, I got that the source of the confusion was collision on the definitions 1.5.1, 1.5.2: the first claims the base space to be a vector topological space, when the second defines the base space as just a set without mentioning any structure. Any idea what might mean such an ambiguity? 
All said seems to be pretty fair in the case of vector topological spaces, but not that clear when the base space is naked

Comment: There is no real ambiguity there. The first definition tells you what a **local** vector bundle is. Note here that the base space is an open subset of some ambient vector space. A vector bundle then is just a set (no ambient space here) together with a vector bundle structure which carries the relevant information.

Comment: @P-A, understood. Thank you!